# function argument in filter of dplyr in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

```
filter(data, function(x) sum(is.na(x))>2)
```

I want to use this piece of code to get a subset of data which contains rows involve less than 2 NA values, however, the error occurs:

**Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector**

Just wondering the reason and how could I deal with it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) < 2)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data[rowSums(is.na(data)) < 2,]
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c(2, 3, NA), col2 = c(2, NA, NA), col3 = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i just feel a little bit confused with your initial answer mentioned 'filter_all', however, it has been solved now.